# Highcharts X axis categories name gets only shows 1 character

Tags: r, highcharts

I created a column and line chart with highcharts.

X axis category names have been appearing fine in other charts created with the same code but now I encounter an issue where the entire category name gets cut short with only the first letter only displayed in the chart.

For example a category should read 'Run' but it only shows up as 'R'.

I also noted that this occurs in charts where there is only 1 category to display (so like a lone column chart with only one column displayed).

Would appreciate some help here :)

```
highchart() %>%
hc_title(text = "Creative Performance") %>%
hc_yAxis_multiples(
list(title = list(text = "Spend"),labels=list(format ='${value:,.2f}'), min=0, max=max(data_creative_trueview$Spend), showFirstLabel= TRUE,showLastLabel=TRUE,opposite = FALSE),
list(title = list(text = "TrueView: CPCV"),min=0,max = max(data_creative_trueview$`TrueView: CPCV`)+0.5, labels = list(format = "${value:,.2f}"),showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE)) %>%
hc_add_series(data = data_creative_trueview, type= "column", hcaes(y=Spend), name="Spend") %>%
hc_add_series(data = data_creative_trueview, type = "line", hcaes(y=`TrueView: CPCV`), name="TrueView: CPCV", yAxis=1) %>%
hc_xAxis(title="Creative", categories=data_creative_trueview$Creative) %>%
hc_tooltip(pointFormat = '${point.y:,.2f}') %>%
emphasized text hc_legend(align = "right", verticalAlign = "top")
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer right after I posted this. Apparently this is a common issue. Categories must be provided as a list when there is only one category. Refer to: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/173

Answer (score 0):

In my case `xlabel={{"64"}}` showed only 6 where as `xlabel={{"64",}}` gave me 64 which was what I have wanted.